# SSL Failed authorization procedure

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to use letsencrypt but am getting this error message:

The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain. 
Failed to connect to 139.162.193.10:443 for TLS-SNI-01 challenge

Comment: make sure you have firewall rules that allow a connection in to port 443. You'll also need to run the standalone client on the machine that DNS points to for the domain you are trying to get a certificate for.

Comment: Thanks! That solved the problem, port 443 was being blocked by my firewall.